# How is uplink MU MIMO established

Tags: digital-communications

My question is more suitable for communication but im trying here. If you guys think there is a better suitable place please let me know.

I understand the concept of DL MU MIMO in the sense that a number of users are served in the same time and frequency resources but they are separated in the spatial domain by precoding at the base station.

However what does it mean to have UL MU-MIMO?  Since the users are distributed and precoding is at different UE I am not sure what is meant by UL MU MIMO. Does it mean we allow users to transmit in same subband? And does 5G NR support UL MU MIMO?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In downlink MU-MIMO, the MU part refers to the base station serving multiple UEs. In uplink MU-MIMO, the MU part refers to multiple UEs transmitting their packet to the base station in the same time-frequency cell. The base station can use a multiuser detector such as zero-forcing (less common) or MMSE (more common) to receive multiple signals overlapping in time and frequency. In TDD mode, the base station assumes that the DL and UL channels have reciprocity ($\mathbf{H}_{DL}=\mathbf{H}_{UL}$) and so the zero-forcing or MMSE receiver will use the same channel information that was used for precoding.

Both DL MU-MIMO and UL MU-MIMO are supported as options in 5G NR.